# how do i print an input but remove one word per line?

Tags: python-3.x, string, for-loop

This is the code to do the opposite of what I want to do. This adds a word per line but I want to remove a word per line. Is there a way to reverse this loop?

```py
lst = input("Enter a phrase: ")

word = lst.split()

for i in range(len(word)):
    print(' '.join(word[:i]))
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your range to [loop backwards](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range):

```py
lst = input("Enter a phrase: ")

word = lst.split()

for i in range(len(word), 0, -1):
    print(' '.join(word[:i]))
print(lst)
```

Displays:

```
Enter a phrase: I like pizza
I like pizza
I like
I
I like pizza
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it helps:

```
lst = input("Enter a phrase: ")

words = lst.split()

while words:
    print(' '.join(words))
    words.pop(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a little change to the slice index

```
print(' '.join(word[:len(word)-i]))
```